# tensorflow accuracy python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm facing a problem with CNN. Having the code below I'm trying to recognize numbers as it is defined in dicLabelsNumbers dictionary. I have 90 images, 9 of each number 0-9 and repeat it 100 times. But something has to be wrong in my code because whatever parameters in my CNN I change there is no difference in accuracy which is always precise number 0.101123594. It never changes. Please tell me:

1. if my procedure of reading pictures from disc is correct
2. what can be a reason for getting always the same accuracy
3. if I understand if I'm training a CNN on 90 pictures and then evaluate CNN on the same pictures then I should obtain 100% of accuracy. Is it correct?

My images are a bmp of a strict size 16 x 18.

```
    dicLabelsNumbers = {
'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9
      }

    def cnn_model_mk(features, labels, mode):

      input_layer = tf.reshape(features, [-1, 16, 18, 1])

      conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=input_layer, filters=16, kernel_size=[3, 3], padding="same", activation=tf.nn.relu)
      pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=1)
      conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=pool1, filters=32, kernel_size=[3, 3], padding="same", activation=tf.nn.relu)
      pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=1)
      pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 14*16*32])
      dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
      dropout = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=dense, rate=0.2, training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
      logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=len(dicLabelsNumbers))

      predictions = {
          "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
          "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
      }
      if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)

      loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels, logits=logits)

      if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss=loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

      eval_metric_ops = {"accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels, predictions=predictions["classes"])}
      return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)


    def _parse_function(filename, label):
      image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
      image_decoded = tf.image.decode_bmp(image_string)
      image_resized = tf.image.resize_images(image_decoded, [16, 18])
      image_resized = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image_resized)
      image_resized = tf.reshape(image_resized, [16, 18, 1])
      return image_resized, label

    def my_input_fn():
      filespath = "./Signs/"
      root = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(filespath + 'char.xml').getroot()

      filenames = []
      labels = []

      i = 0
      for child in root:
        filename = filespath + child.get("file")
        label = dicLabelsNumbers[child.get("tag")]

        filenames.append(filename)
        labels.append(label)
        i += 1

        if i > 90:
          break

      filenames = tf.constant(filenames)
      labels = tf.constant(labels)

      dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
      dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
      dataset = dataset.repeat(100)
      dataset_batched = dataset.batch(1)
      iterator = dataset_batched.make_one_shot_iterator()

      return iterator.get_next()

    def main(unused_argv):

      mnist_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=cnn_model_mk, model_dir=dir)
      mnist_classifier.train(input_fn=my_input_fn, steps=10000)
      eval_results = mnist_classifier.evaluate(input_fn=my_input_fn)
      print(eval_results)



    if __name__ == "__main__":
      tf.app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The same accuracy is "chance": a 1 in 10 chance of picking the right label. Your network hasn’t learned about the images.

You are correct that if you train and test on the same images, it is possible to completely model the dataset and get 100% accuracy but it still requires training. With such a small dataset, you may require many epochs for this.

If you haven’t already, you should try whitening your input images (there’s a TensorFlow function for whitening) and normalising your input data so that the pixel values are in the range 0-1 (not 0-255).

I’m not familiar with TensorFlow dataset classes but it looks like you set a batch size of 1. I think this might cause your weights to oscillate rather than converge.

Can you output your loss? If there is a problem with the inputs, loss will show it. Loss should decrease somehow over the training steps.

Comment: I manage to solve my problem. In this case there is no need for dropout layer. After removing it CNN starts to works as it should.